# How to show or hide a button depending on the page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm actually kinda new to React, and I'm still learning, so I cannot figure out how to display my button depending on which page I currently am on my app.
I'm using Router v6.
This is my Router with my components inside:

```
     <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route
            path="/CountryPage"
            element={<CountryPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

This is my navbar:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar-container">
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul className="navbar">
            <li>
              <Link to="/" className="home"> <AiOutlineLeft /> </Link>
            </li>
            <li data-testid="tab-name">
              Current Tab
            </li>
            <li>
              <BsFillGearFill className="settings" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

So all I want is to display the button that is `<li> <Link to="/" className="home"> <AiOutlineLeft /> </Link> </li>` only if I am not in the `HomePage` So if I am in the Homepage I don't want to show anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location.href` is a out-of-the-box JS method you should use if you don't have your routing managed by some better library (like react router). Also, here, instead of just the pathname, you actually have to check the **entire URL**.
So your corrected code for this method would be

```
{ window.location.href !=== "yoursubdomian.yourdomain.extension/" && <li> <Link to="/" className="home"> <AiOutlineLeft /> </Link> </li>
```

My advice would be that try a systematic approach using the provisions React Router itself provides

Use the `useLocation()` hook to extract the `pathname` of the current route and check it for rendering the `<Link/>`

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
 
  return (
    <nav className="navbar-container">
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul className="navbar">
            {location.pathname !=="/" && 
               <li>
                 <Link to="/" className="home"> <AiOutlineLeft /> </Link>
               </li>
            }
            <li data-testid="tab-name">
              Current Tab
            </li>
            <li>
              <BsFillGearFill className="settings" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Comment: This actually worked! I couldn't think of it before, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add a vote to this answer so that other people asking the question find a solution ?

Comment: Hey, I would definitely do it, but my account is kinda new, so I cannot do it yet, I'm so sorry.